# reducing x axis gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, axis

I am struggling to find a way to reduce an x axis with gnuplot. 
I am plotting two different data set and , if you look at my plot
[(PLOT)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gn6o2.jpg),
I have a lot a space between the two data set I am plotting. I would like to "remove" them because if I do so, people will understand that the single data set is similar to a sinusoidal signal. Looking at this plot, one cannot say so.

I did not find anything useful in the web. Can you help me?

Thank you,
Martina.

Comment: Please always provide some data as text! How is your data organized? Multiple files or a single file with multiple columns or multiple blocks?

Answer (score 0):

You can have two plots use different x axes, but the same y axis, by specifying `axes x2y1` for one of them. For example, something like

```
set xtics nomirror
set x2tics
plot "file1" w p, "file2" axes x2y1 w p
```

should do what you want. For other possible combinations see `help axes`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your tips. It will be useful in the future.
However this does not solve my problem. In fact in this way I will have the two dataset overlapped, as in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u9DG.png).  Instead I would like to have the two data set as a continuum, avoiding all the space you can see in the plot of my first post.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Please always provide your code and data as text. It is important to know how your data is organized.

From the ranges of the plot you show (`5.53e8 to 5.71e8`), I assume that you have time data which is either from 1987/88 or from 2017/18 depending if you were using gnuplot 4.x or 5.x. The zero reference date has changed from Jan 1st 2000 in gnuplot 4.x to Jan 1st 1970 in gnuplot 5.x.

```
gnuplot 4.x
2017-07-18 02:10  to  2017-07-18 04:06
2018-01-30 23:10  to  2018-01-31 01:40
```

or

```
gnuplot 5.x
1987-07-19 02:10  to  1987-07-19 04:06
1988-01-31 23:10  to  1988-02-01 01:40
```

Anyway, your two datasets have both a range of about only 2 hours, but they are separated by about half a year. As you already noticed this will not give a reasonable plot if you simply plot them as timedata.
Therefore, you simply need to shift the second dataset such that it will be "connected" with the first one.
As a consequence, absolute time/date do not make sense anymore, but relative hours `"%tH"` from the beginning of the first dataset will be suitable (check `help time_specifiers examples`).

Hence, you have to find out the first and last date/time values of your datasets.
One possibility would be to use `stats` (check `help stats`) and `timecolumn()` (check `help timecolumn`). You will find these values in `t1_min, t1_max, t2_min` and `t2_max`.

For comparison, the code below plots your graph as you did and as you would expect.

**Code:**

```
### plot timedata with offset (gnuplot 5.x)
reset session

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"

# create some random test data
set print $Data1
    t0 = strptime(myTimeFmt,"2017-07-18 02:10")
    t1 = strptime(myTimeFmt,"2017-07-18 04:06")
    do for [t=t0:t1:5*60] {    # every 5 minutes
        print sprintf("%s %g",strftime(myTimeFmt,t), rand(0))
    }
set print $Data2
    t0 = strptime(myTimeFmt,"2018-01-30 23:10")
    t1 = strptime(myTimeFmt,"2018-01-31 01:40")
    do for [t=t0:t1:5*60] {    # every 5 minutes
        print sprintf("%s %g",strftime(myTimeFmt,t), rand(0))
    }
set print

set key out right
set multiplot layout 2,1
    set format x "%b %d\n%Y" timedate
    plot $Data1 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):3 w lp pt 6 lc "red"  ti "Data1", \
         $Data2 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):3 w lp pt 6 lc "blue" ti "Data2"

    stats $Data1 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)) name "t1" nooutput
    stats $Data2 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)) name "t2" nooutput
    set format x "%tH:%tM" timedate
    plot $Data1 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t1_min):3                 w lp pt 6 lc "red"  ti "Data1", \
         $Data2 u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)-t2_min+(t1_max-t1_min)):3 w lp pt 6 lc "blue" ti "Data2"

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]